# Comparison between Javascript/Ajax in PHP and Struts2

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, html, struts2

I had a little bit of experience in JavaScript + AJAX in PHP, but I've never had it before in Struts2. I had the habit in PHP which contains a div that I need to be dynamic, and so in the form there is for example a select to call a JavaScript function, that JavaScript function can be defined in the header or in a .js file, and so those JavaScript files which create ajax object and send parameters to another PHP page which contains the same name of the div to change in the first page. But, how can I project this on Struts2? Where to call the JavaScript function and the action function? Would struts2-jquery-plugin make it easier? Unfortunately I don't any example in the both cases (native Ajax, either jQuery plugin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing "raw" JavaScript/jQuery the framework doesn't really matter. You can write JS/JQ as you would with any other server framework–the client-side code is essentially identical.

The [jQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/) *does* make simple use cases much simpler. For complex use cases, it's a bit more of a tossup. It provides a pub/sub mechanism, however, which is pretty flexible.

Comment: Thank you. For jquery plugin, how can I declare the result of the action in the struts.xml? Should it be of json type?? <action name="ajaxTest" method="ajaxTest" class="action.AjaxAction" >
   <result name="ajax"  type="json" />
  </action>

Comment: @user1459961 There are a wide variety of examples in the plugin showcase app.

Comment: Do you mean this website http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action ? I've been to there, but they don't show what they do in struts.xml, they only show code for the jsp page.

Comment: @user1459961 I mean the example code available for download. Like from the [project's downloads](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/downloads/list).

Comment: Ok, thank you for the information. Well, here what they made for struts.xml : <struts>
    <package name="showcase" extends="struts-default,json-default" namespace="/">
    </package>
</struts> , and here what they made in the action class : @Action(value = "/remote-div", results = {
    @Result(location = "remote-div.jsp", name = "success")
  }) . what is /remote-div? the name of the division or of an action? if it is the name of the action, i can't see any mapping in the xml file... I'm lost. Thank you again and sorry if I'm disturbing you.

Comment: @user1459961 Don't need to see it, I have the showcase apps. If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Comment: Okay, sorry. I'll post a new question and mark this as resolved. Thank you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14761/discussion-between-user1459961-and-dave-newton)